# Getting tag values after xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<Order>
  <jobDetails>
    <Question>
      <QuestionNumber>1</QuestionNumber>
      <QuestionResponse>
        <Response>Value</Response>
      </QuestionResponse>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <QuestionNumber>2</QuestionNumber>
      <QuestionResponse>
        <Response>AnotherValue</Response>
      </QuestionResponse>
    </Question>
  </jobDetails>
</Order>
```

I am using XSLT 1.0 to get the value of the Response if the question number is 2: I need to further query it and output a different value depending upon it is.

I have tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="Order">
  <xsl:for-each select="jobDetails/Question">
    <xsl:variable name="theSet" select="QuestionNumber[string(.)='2']" />
    <xsl:if test="$theSet">
      <xsl:when test="QuestionResponse/Response = 'Value'"><Response>SomeValue</Response></xsl:when> 
      <xsl:when test="QuestionResponse/Response = 'AnotherValue'"><Response>SomeOtherValue</Response></xsl:when>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

... but the XSLT does not validate.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Is there only one question #2 in the entire XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. If you want to test the response to Question #2, you can do so directly, without going through all the other questions:

```
<xsl:template match="/Order">
    <xsl:variable name="resp2" select="jobDetails/Question[QuestionNumber='2']/QuestionResponse/Response" />
    <response>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$resp2='Value'">SomeValue</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$resp2='AnotherValue'">SomeOtherValue</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </response>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this assumes there is only one Question #2 in the entire XML (you haven't answered my question about this). Otherwise we'd need instructions how to output more than one result.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know that you could write selects in that way. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working - I print the value of "resp2" and it is empty. I'm wondering whether it's got anything to do with the template match as the <jobDetails> tag is within a further set of <Order> tags. I'm using <xsl:template match="Order"> at a higher level.

Comment: @GarlicBread Yes, the above assumes that jobDetails is the root element of your XML. Please edit your question and show us a minimal but complete example of your XML and the expected result.

Comment: Done, with apologies.

Comment: Works a treat - many thanks. Yes, there is only one question 2 in the source XML.